# Nondeterministic logging using JRuby + Tomcat6 + log4j

Tags: tomcat, logging, jruby, tomcat6

I'm using log4j for logging in my JRuby on Rails application. Every single time I push the application out, logs are getting appended to different end destinations. Sometimes it's catalina.out. sometimes it's localhost-date.log. sometimes it's catalina-date.log.

I'm not really sure why it's not the same every single time.

what are some things I can check as to why logs are so unreliable in my environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty weird indeed - are you by chance using [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) as well?

It's just a short in the dark, but every time I experience something weird with [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html) and/or *Commons Logging* I immediately recall and revisit the well documented problems with the latter specifically (see [Think again before adopting the commons-logging API](http://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html), or the even more comprehensive version [Taxonomy of class loader problems encountered when using Jakarta Commons Logging](http://articles.qos.ch/classloader.html)), concisely summarized in delfuego's answer for [log4j and the thread context classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1974775/45773):

> You appear to have stumbled upon the major problem with log4j (and the
>   Apache Commons Logging library), namely that they have a ridiculously
>   hard time discovering and interacting with the right classloaders as
>   they're being used.

Given the very nature of the classloader issue, I could imagine it tripping your problem as well, i.e. depending on which classloader currently ended up wiring in your logging, it might use a different logging properties search path and respective defaults as well, see [Why can't log4j find my properties file in a J2EE or WAR application?](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.5):

> The short answer: the log4j classes and the properties file are not
>   within the scope of the same classloader.
>
> The long answer (and what to do about it): J2EE or Servlet containers
>   utilize Java's class loading system. Sun changed the way classloading
>   works with the release of Java 2. In Java 2, classloaders are arranged
>   in a hierarchial parent-child relationship. When a child classloader
>   needs to find a class or a resource, it first delegates the request to
>   the parent. [...]

The mentioned problems are usually easy to remedy by switching to [Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)](http://www.slf4j.org/) indeed (which happens to have the same author as log4j btw., Ceki Gülcü), as likewise suggested by delfuego:

> [...] the take-home message is that one of the primary driving forces for
>   the new logging framework [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) was to eliminate these issues
>   entirely. You might want to swap it in and see if your life is made
>   any easier.

Finally, John's (as of today unresolved) adventure with [Logging with log4j on tomcat jruby-rack for a Rails 3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571790/logging-with-log4j-on-tomcat-jruby-rack-for-a-rails-3-application) seems to hint on respective issues and a possible solution via [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) as well.

Good luck!